# Is there a way to check if text is in cyrillics or latin using C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to check if text is in cyrillics or latin using C#?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use a Regex and check for `\p{IsCyrillic}`, for example:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(stringToCheck, @"\p{IsCyrillic}"))
{
    // there is at least one cyrillic character in the string
}
```

This would be true for the string "abcабв" because it contains at least one cyrillic character. If you want it to be false if there are non cyrillic characters in the string, use:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(stringToCheck, @"\P{IsCyrillic}"))
{
    // there are only cyrillic characters in the string
}
```

This would be false for the string "abcабв", but true for "абв".

To check what the IsCyrillic named block or other named blocks contain, have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks

Comment: Not working with dots, commas, etc.

Answer (score 6):

How about this ?

```
string pattern = @"\p{IsCyrillic}";
if ( Regex.Matches(textInput, pattern).Count > 0)
{
    // contains cyrillics' characters.
}
```

If you want to check that contains cyrillics characters more than x characters Change the right hand numeric value.

Our system recieved spam email that contains cyrillics' characters roughly 30% of
full of text;so, couldn't decide whether 100% or 0%

Answer (score -4):

Here is another solution for this problem

```
public bool isCyrillic(string textInput)
{
bool rezultat=true;
 string pattern = @"[абвгдѓежзѕијклљмнњопрстќуфхцчџш]";
        char[] textArray = textInput.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < textArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(textArray[i].ToString(),pattern))
            {
                rezultat = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return rezultat;
}
```

Comment: You really don't want to do that. Checking every character by itself is not a good idea here. If you want to make sure, that every character of the string is cyrillic, you can use `!Regex.IsMatch(textInput, @"\P{IsCyrillic}")` (notice the capital P, which negates the check). But what if there are numbers or characters like "!,." etc.? Your check would return false then, do you want this behaviour?

Comment: yes you are right I will have to put all characters in string pattern in my way.Your solution is fine .